# Calculate Height of a 2D Array of 0's and 1's in C

Tags: c, arrays, function, loops, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to write a program that finds the height of pixels of an "image".
The "image" is a 2D array of 0's and 1's, 0's being white space, 1's being black pixels.

The nested loop goes through the array from left to right, first through the x-axis, then the y-axis.

I'm trying to find the highest value of the y-value. The plan is to store all the y values over 0 in a new array, and find the highest y-value. However, the below code has only stored y=5 into the array for some reason.

I'm thinking the order is wrong maybe?

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_X       20
#define MAX_Y       20

void printImage(int image[MAX_X][MAX_Y]);
int countBlackPixels(int image[MAX_X][MAX_Y]);
int findYPixel(int image[MAX_X][MAX_Y]);

//function prototypes

void processImage(int image[MAX_X][MAX_Y]) {

    int yPixel;
    yPixel = findYPixel(image);
    printf("Height: %d\n", yPixel);

}

//Height
//Calculates height of image 

int findYPixel(int image[MAX_X][MAX_Y]) {
    int x, y, yPixel, i;
    int new_array[MAX_Y-1];
    x = 0;
    yPixel=-1;
    while (x < MAX_X) {
        y = MAX_Y-1;
        while (y > 0) {
            if (image[x][y] == 1) {
                yPixel=y;
                }
            y = y - 1;
        }
        x = x + 1;
    }
    return yPixel;
}
```

Does anyone see where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This loop assigns *all values* in your array to the current `y` value:

```
for(i=0; i < MAX_Y; i++) {
    new_array[i] = y;  //store all y values in a new array
}
```

That's why you end up with just one value at the end.

You don't even need to store an array of `y` values. As soon as you find your first non-zero entry in the 2D-array, you can return the current `y` value as the answer. (This assumes you start searching at the top of the image and work your way down.)

Even if you loop from the bottom up, you still don't need an array. Just update `yPixel = y;` each time you encounter a non-zero pixel. At the end of the loop, `yPixel` will be the y-value for the highest non-blank pixel. You should probably start with `yPixel = -1` or something, which helps you identify the case when the whole image is blank.

Comment: That would be a lot easier actually, at the moment it is searching the image from the bottom up, I'll see if I can switch it.

Comment: @BMarino - Yes, I think it would be better to just switch it to loop from `MAX_Y-1` to `0`. However, even if you loop the other way, you don't need to store an array. See my updated answer.